# python object oriented programming methods

Tags: python, oop

I have defined the below code but there seems to be issues regarding methods `load` and `damage`.

(edited based on suggestions by ShadowRanger):

```
class RangedWeapon(Weapon):
        def __init__(self, name, min_dmg, max_dmg):
            super().__init__(name, min_dmg, max_dmg)
            self.shots=0

        def shots_left(self):
            return self.shots

        def load(self, ammo):
            if ammo.weapon_type()==self.name:
                self.shots+=ammo.get_quantity()
                ammo.remove_all()

        def damage(self):
            if self.shots==0:
                return 0
            else:
                self.shots-=1
                return super().damage()
```

_

```
bow = RangedWeapon('bow', 10, 40)
crossbow = RangedWeapon('crossbow', 15, 45)
arrows = Ammo('arrow', bow, 5)
bolts = Ammo('bolt', crossbow, 10)

bow.load(arrows)
print(bow.shots_left()) # should return 5
print(arrows.get_quantity()) #should return 0
```

But for `print(bow.shots_left())` I got 0 and `print(arrows.get_quantity())` I got 5 instead. They are reversed. I think my problem is that I didn't load the Ammo quantity? I'm not very sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
class Ammo(Thing):
    def __init__(self, name, weapon, quantity):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=weapon
        self.quantity=quantity

    def get_quantity(self):
        return self.quantity

    def weapon_type(self):
        return self.weapon.name

    def remove_all(self):
        self.quantity=0
```

Comment: what does the `Ammo` class look like?

Comment: Your load function should use `ammo` variable not the class `Ammo`

Comment: I don’t know how this code is executing in your interpreter; I can already eyeball at least two runtime errors that would derail this program’s execution

Comment: @taylorswift: That was my initial impression, but it turns out one of the big errors (comparing a method to a string) makes sure all the other broken code paths never execute.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you see this is the kind of thing we take for granted in compiled languages…

Answer (score 0):

Primary problem: `Ammo`'s `weapon_type` is a method, not an attribute or property, and you didn't call it, so you're comparing the method itself to the `name`, not the result of calling it. This is the reason why `load` does nothing; no method is ever equal to a string.

Other issues:

It looks like you're calling methods on the class, not on the instances. You pass `ammo` (an instance) as an argument, then call methods on `Ammo` (the class).

Similarly, your `damage` method should probably be calling `super().damage()` not `Weapon.damage()`, since the latter doesn't use your instance state. And you've got typos (`shots` vs. `shot`) that should make this code non-functional in other ways.

Short version: This code is broken in a million ways, and you'll run into each of them as you fix the previous issues.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've edited my code such that now `damage` works well, but after calling `weapon_type` by calling`ammo.weapon_type()==self.name`, the outputs are still reversed. How can I improve my code? thanks!

Comment: @elle: The outputs are not reversed, not unless there is something truly bizarre hiding in your implementation of `Weapon` or `Thing`. I just ran your code (substituting a trivial definition of `Weapon`, and just not inheriting from the irrelevant `Thing`) and it worked exactly as it is supposed to, the `bow` is loaded, the `arrows` are empty.

Comment: Side-note: Idiomatically, there is no reason to have "getter" methods like `get_quantity`. Just access the `quantity` attribute directly. If you ever need to give it more logic, you can just reimplement as an `@property` (renaming any attribute to `_quantity` without changing the interface exposed to consumers of your class.